# Jquery appending text to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The aim is to append a line of text into the element below.

```
anchorElement = "<a id='anchor" + countWide + "' class=\"boxOPT oneplustwo\" alt=\'"+ image_website +"' style=\"cursor:pointer;width:"+ itemWidth + "px"+";height:"+anchorHeight+";position:absolute;left:"+ locationLeft + "px"+";top:0.3%;\" ><p class=\"popupDynamic\"> " + popupImageTitles[i] + "</p>";
```

this code is contained within a loop so each time a new anchor is created and given an incremented ID (countwide) for for example 'anchor1' 'anchor2'

What I need is to be able to append this variable below as part of the p element inside this anchor

```
image_price
```

I have tried this with no progress.

```
$("#anchor1").append(image_price);
```

obviously we need the id in the line above to increment in line with the loop.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't put a block level element inside an inline element such as `<a>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#anchor" + countWide + " .popupDynamic").append(image_price);
```

Explanation:

I have just updated the selector so that it would pick up the child of the `#anchor + countWide`(this means anchor plus the dynamic ID) with the class of `.popupDynamic` and append the price to it.

Comment: This worked for appending the price, so thanks! :) any idea on how I could change the 'anchor1' part of the id to take into account a dynamic variable name? for example '#anchor3'

Comment: `$("#anchor"+variable+" .popupDynamic")...`

Comment: @user2696787 I've added the functionality to update the anchorId dynamically. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `countWide` variable in your `selector`, this way :

```
$("#anchor"+countWide+" .popupDynamic").append(image_price);
```